# Increment param in file using bash

Tags: shell-script

How I can increment through clients seat_num using bash?
I have this file:

```
$ cat test
    client1
    name="", possition="", seat_num=""
    client2
    name="", possition="", seat_num=""
```

I need this kind of increment:

```
client1
name="", possition="", seat_num="1"
client2
name="", possition="", seat_num="2"
```

I tried this approach, but it does not do what I wanted:

```
$ while read -r line; do i=1;echo $line|sed -e 's/seat_num=""/seat_num="$i"/';((i++)); done <<< "$(grep -A 2 client test)"
        client1
        name="", possition="", seat_num="$i"
        client2
        name="", possition="", seat_num="$i"
```

Comment: What is the start value of `seat_num` in `test` file? If it is not a number, it cannot be incremented.

Comment: lets assume all clients in input file will have seat_num="1", how then it can be incremented for each client? Meaning that client1 should have seat_num="1", client2 -   seat_num="2" ...

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments, as it's all  too easy to miss. Put everything in your question. Also, don't use "Edit" or "Update" to append details - but instead include the new information in your question as if you'd had it when you first posted. That way, it's much easier to read - and hopefully answer

Comment: Your starting point `seat_num=""` isn't a number

Answer (score 0):

`seat_num` starts `1`.

You can try:

```bsh
i=1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if grep -Fq 'seat_num=""' <<< "$line"; then
        sed "s/seat_num=\"\"/seat_num=\"$((i++))\"/" <<< "$line"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    fi
done <<< "$(grep -A 2 client test)"
```

Output:

```
client1
name="", possition="", seat_num="1"
client2
name="", possition="", seat_num="2"
```

`i` increments if line includes `seat_num=""`.

Comment: I would like to increment it through clients. To increment through a file simple sed would be enough. I need this:
client1
name="", possition="", seat_num="1"
client2
name="", possition="", seat_num="2"

Comment: Please ADD THIS TO YOUR QUESTION

Comment: (1) Instead of `grep > /dev/null`, you can use `grep -q`. (2) As `seat_num=""` is a fixed string, you should use `grep -F` for performance reasons. (3) You could increment `i` directly by using `$((i++))` inside your `sed` replacement string if you wish. (4) [Better to use `printf` instead of `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). (5) To avoid issues if last line does not have newline, you should set IFS --> `while IFS= read -r line; do`

Comment: Thank you helpful information!

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} /seat_num=/{$6=++n}1' test
```

- `FS=OFS="\""` Set Input and Output Field Separator to `"`.
- If `seat_num=` is found in a line, change 6th field to `++n`.
- `var=++n` means increment `n` first, then set `var`. Compared to `var=n++` which would set `var` and increment afterwards. An undefined variable in `awk` has value of `0`, so you want to increment first (--> `++n`).

To edit your file in place, you could use `-i inplace` if available.
If not available, add  `> test.tmp && mv test.tmp test`

Answer (score 0):

Although your question specifies "incrementing" (to add to an existing number, often by 1), the impression I get from reading your other comments is that you would really like to iterate through the clients in a file and read the number after "client" in one row, and then make the seat_num in the following row equal to the same number.

If that is the case, then the following sed command works for me, where test has the same contents as in the question. (I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to do it):

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/client\([0-9]*\)\(\n[^\n]*\)seat_num=""/client\1\2seat_num="\1"/g' <<< cat test
```

This starts with a magic string from @Wiktor Stribizew's answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression): "(`H;1h;$!d;x;` slurps the file into memory)". Reading the man page, I think it is copying the line of pattern read from the input into a "Hold space", then deleting the pattern and reading another line of pattern from the input until the input is ended, then swapping the "Hold space" back to the "Pattern space" ready to run the following substitution. However, I'm still not clear on the details, so I would be happy to be corrected.

In the substitution, we look for `client` followed by 0 or more digits (`[0-9]*`), and we use escaped parentheses `\(` and `\)` to remember the digits. Then we look for a newline followed by 0 or more not-newlines (so that we read only up to the next `seat_num`), followed by the next `seat_num=""` - again using escaped parentheses to remember what came before the `seat_num=`.

We replace all of this with the original `client` text and the remembered number (`\1` uses the first remembered parameter) followed by the second remembered parameter, then the original `seat_num="` text and a repeat of the first remembered parameter (the digit(s) after `client`) and the final `"`. As the pattern now contains the whole file, we use the `g` command to do this substitution globally.